# How to work with OneDrive files in Azure Container Instances?

Tags: azure, onedrive, power-automate, azure-container-instances

I want to use Azure Container Instances (*ACI*) to process larger media files (up to 1GB in size for both input and output). The files are stored in a shared OneDrive for Business folder. Processed files should be stored at the same location with a suffix added to the filename.

It seems only [Azure file share](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-volume-azure-files) can be directly used with ACI, but I'd like to prevent having an additional storage involved if possible. FUSE doesn't seem to be working, either.

While the actual process works perfectly fine, I'm still struggling with the OneDrive in- and output - especially due to the very restrictive Power Automate quotas.

As for the **input** (OneDrive -> Container), I got a working version when creating a public share link with a short expiration for each file, which I can then process from within the container. While this isn't perfect, it at least works as expected.

The **output** (Container -> OneDrive) part seems quite hard. Only `simple item upload` (<4MB) and `resumable item upload` are valid for [work with OneDrive for Business](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/concepts/upload). Creating a custom client application leveraging the OneDrive API just for the final upload proess seems overkill and would require a custom Container.

Do you see any better way to handle the *input* part, and any straightforward solution for the *output* one? Maybe one involving additional cloud services?

Comment: Can Logic apps form a better solution for this? - Does your container expose an endpoint which can return the processed binary file to a logic app? - if yes,  Logic app will integrate well with One drive.

Comment: @AbhinavPandey you're right Logic Apps might be a better choice, but they still can't directly handle large files easily. The container doesn't expose any endpoint, but just invokes a CLI which does some processing and produces a new file.